# How to model this sort of cylinder into cone into flat edge shape?

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

I'm not *too* bad at modeling - and have built the rest of the model, but this particular shape really has me stumped. I've tried going down the subdiv route, and also boolean - but I cannot seem to get the right curves and it all goes to pot when bringing supporting edge loops into the mesh.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could try it this way:

- Create a 32 vertex cylinder, mirror it on 2 axis:

[image]

- Pull the central face with *Proportional Editing* activated, choose the *Sharp* option:

[image]

- Create additional edge loops:

[image]

- Pull the top face, this time with *Proportional Editing Smooth* option:

[image]

- Rework the topology a bit so that you don't have too stretched faces, add bevels to sharp the edges:

[image]

- Here is what it gives with a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]